# order a Data Frame based on the order of items in a list

Tags: python, pandas

Given a pd.DataFrame()

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | something | AL |
| y | in | CA |
| z | place | FL |

And a list with items [FL, CA AL] start at FL and end at AL

If I want to order the pandas data frame with the same order as shown in this list, can that be done ? I do not want COL3 to be the index, but that the order of df and list be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an ordered [`Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html):

```
order = ['FL', 'CA', 'AL']

out = df.sort_values(by='COL3',
                     key=lambda s: pd.Categorical(s, categories=order,
                                                     ordered=True))
```

Alternatively, using a dictionary (which enables undefined values, they will be sorted last):

```
order = ['FL', 'CA', 'AL']
d = dict({k: i for i, k in enumerate(order)})
# {'FL': 0, 'CA': 1, 'AL': 2}

out = df.sort_values(by='COL3', key=lambda s: s.map(d))
```

Output:

```
  COL1       COL2 COL3
2    z      place   FL
1    y         in   CA
0    x  something   AL
```